# How to use sound effects in Java 8? Snake eats apple

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I wrote Snake code, and want to add a sound effect when snake eats an apple. I copyied a code from some guy on YT, but it doesn't work to me. Can somebody explain me how to do this?

Code:

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.Main;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class AppleEatSoundEffect {
    public static Mixer mixer;
    public static Clip clip;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mixer.Info[] mixInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixInfos[0]);

        DataLine.Info dataInfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, null);
        try {
            clip = (Clip) mixer.getLine(dataInfo);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
            lue.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            URL soundURL = Main.class.getResource("NotBad.wav");
            AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL);
            clip.open(audioStream);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
            lue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException uafe) {
            uafe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

            clip.start();
            do {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (clip.isActive());
        }
    }
```

Compiler says thas something wrong with `clip = (Clip) mixer.getLine(dataInfo);`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface Clip
>       at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer.getLine(PortMixer.java:131)

Comment: Why are you importing `com.sun.tools.javac.Main`?

Comment: The [`javasound`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) tag wiki has a correct example of setting up a `Clip`. That code from YouTube looks like garbage, honestly. I don't know what they think they're doing with `mixInfos[0]`.

Comment: You learn new things each day. (kidding) @shmosel This shouldn't be here at all.

Comment: @shomel idk, Im really new to those things :)

Comment: *"really new"* How did you go with the code linked by @Radiodef?

Comment: `URL soundURL = Main.class.getResource("NotBad.wav");` I'd advise to print out the URL immediately afterwards. What value is returned?

Comment: BTW @Radiodef, nice additions to the Java Sound WIKI. 

Comment: So, now a tried this code:
`import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
 
try {
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Main.class.getResource("beep-07.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(null);
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
        }catch (Throwable t){}
    }` 
There are no errors, but no sound is played...

Comment: 1) *"tried this code:"* Please [edit] it into the question where code is readable! 2) *"`catch (Throwable t){} }` There are no errors, but no sound is played..."* The `{}` in the `catch` means you have no information on what errors might have occurred. Change it to `{t.printStackTrace();}`. 3) Where is the code to print out the `soundURL`? 4) Tip: Add @shmosel (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a method which allows you to play audio files, in particular the common WAV or MIDI files. Try it...if you get your desired audio then let me know.

```
public Thread playWav(final File wavFile, final boolean... loopContinuous) {
    String ls = System.lineSeparator();
    // Was a file object supplied?
    if (wavFile == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ls + "playWav() Method Error! "
                + "Sound file object can not be null!" + ls);
    }

    // Does the file exist?
    if (!wavFile.exists()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ls + "playWav() Method Error! "
                + "The sound file specified below can not be found!" + ls
                + "(" + wavFile.getAbsolutePath() + ")" + ls);
    }

    // Play the Wav file from its own Thread.
    Thread t = null;
    try {
        t = new Thread("Audio Thread") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(new Line.Info(Clip.class));
                    audioClip = clip;
                    clip.addLineListener((LineEvent event) -> {
                        if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                            clip.drain();
                            clip.flush();
                            clip.close();
                        }
                    });
                    clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(wavFile));
                    // Are we to loop the audio?
                    if (loopContinuous.length > 0 && loopContinuous[0]) {
                        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                    }
                    clip.start();
                }
                catch (LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return t;
}
```

To use this method simply call it wherever and whenever you want a particular sound effect to be played:

```
File file = new File("resources/NotBad.wav");
playWav(file);
```

**Make sure** the file object points to the correct file location. If you want to loop the audio file as for perhaps game background music then supply boolean true to the optional **loopContinuous** parameter:

```
File file = new File("resources/BackgroundMusic.mid");
playWav(file, true);
```